# Isolated points are open if $|x| \geq 2$?

Tags: general-topology

> **Theorem**: Define $X$ to be a topological space with $|X| \geq 2. $ Then $x \in X$ is an isolated point$\iff$ $\{ x \}$ is open.

I am reading this and the proof proceeds with a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and showing that $U = \{ x \}.$ which uses the fact that $|X| \geq 2.$ From $U \cap X - \{ x \} = \emptyset \implies X - \{ x \} \neq \emptyset$

But I don't understand why can't we say that $U$ is open, and $X \in \tau$, so that is open, then $\{ x \} = U \cap X$, the intersection of two open sets, so it is open. What is wrong with this argument?

**Def**: Define $X$ to be a topological space. A point $x \in A \subset X$ is an isolated point of $A \iff \exists$ an open neighbourhood of $U$ of $x$ such that $U \cap A = \{ x \}$

Comment: Isn't the definition of $x$ being an isolated point that ${x}$ is open?

Comment: Why must $U$ be an open set? (I can't see why it must be, unless you are taking the convention that every neighborhood is open, but I could easily be wrong.)

Comment: @AWertheim, yeah. I thought neighbourhoods are open?

Comment: Actually the proof says "Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood" as well.

Comment: @sidht: it depends on your definition. Some people define neighborhoods to be open, and others do not. See this wikipedia article for more on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_%28mathematics%29. I do not see anything wrong with your proof if $U$ is open by definition.

Comment: So then why is $|X| \geq 2$ necessarily…? Or how might that refute my argument?

Comment: I'm not sure it does. I think that it's more a trivial conclusion is all. If $X = \{x\}$ is your entire space, then of course $\{x\}$ is open. I could be missing something subtle though. I am far from knowledgeable about topology, but the proof you have given makes sense to me (assuming $U$ is open), and I don't see why the conclusion isn't also true for $|X| = 1$ anyway.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of isolated point or the book's name? As pointed out, it depends on definition of neighborhood.

Comment: @user64066, See edit, the "book" is a series of lecture from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuBjzIGUg-E&list=PLpG_ISEhQ6z0Q5MaIvdn5tBJFWfp9fZtQ&index=24)

Comment: @sidht something seems fishy here, what set is $x$ an isolated point of in your theorem?

Comment: @DanZimm, $x$ is an isolated point of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to restate the arguments in my own words for the sake of clarity for myself (and possibly others)

By the definition of an isolated point of a set $A$ we have that there must exist some open neighborhood of $x$, call it $U$, such that
$$
U \cap A = \{ x \}
$$

Now we take $A = X$ so then we get that
$$
U \cap X = \{x\}
$$
and since $U$ and $X$ must be open we have that $\{x\}$ is open.

So, yes, I agree with your argument.

---

As for how the book is presenting theirs by saying let $U$ be the open neighborhood of $x$ such that
$$
U \cap X = \{x\}
$$
(of course this exists since $x$ is an isolated point) then we have
$$
U \cap X \setminus \{x\} = \emptyset
$$
but since $\lvert X \rvert \ge 2$ we know $X \setminus \{x\} \neq \emptyset$ so thus we must have $U = \{x\}$, thus $\{x\}$ is open.

---

I believe the reason they present this argument this way is because you can fairly easily see both sides of the $\iff$ - i.e. you can start from the end and see how to go backwards fairly easily.

I think they only prove this for $\lvert X \rvert \ge 2$ since for $\lvert X \rvert = 1$ the statement is almost trivially true.

Comment: I see, that makes sense in the case of $|X| = 1.$